# Which street address do I use when creating an csr file (for ssl certificate)?

Tags: ssl, openssl, csr

I am creating an .csr file using the following openssl command:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out server.csr
```

The program is asking for several pieces of information including street address.  Do I need to use the address of my server (in Atlanta GA) or the location of my business according to whois (in Chattanooga TN)?

Also, which of the pieces of information are validated by the authority and which sources will they use?

Answer (score 1):

> Which street address do I use when creating an csr file (for ssl certificate)?

There's no hard and fast rules. Attributes like country, state and street address are used to form a Distinguished Name. If you don't want to use it, then don't use it.

Personally, I don't use a street address. If someone needs it, then they can look it up on the website or they can send snail mail to the business' Registered Agent. However, the folks issuing the certificate might require it.

You can see a selection of various attributes in RFC 4514, [Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP): String Representation of Distinguished Names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514).

> Do I need to use the address of my server (in Atlanta GA) or the location of my business according to whois (in Chattanooga TN)?

Typically you would identify the business. If you'd like to add some additional information, there is a description available. However, the folks issuing the certificate might hijack the description attribute.

> Also, which of the pieces of information are validated by the authority and which sources will they use?

That varies by authority. Each authority should provide the information in their Certification Practice Statement (CPS).

Typically, the lower "class" certificates use less rigorous methods. For example, a Class 1 server certificate often uses "domain validation", which is essentially an email to the webmaster of the domain in question. A Class 3 or 4 might require the articles of incorporation of a business.